# Scrollable element, how to change offset top on resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After diving deeper into my scrollable element, I found out that once a user resizes a browser window running the following code, the scrollable won't start scrolling from the point I want it to do (the very moment when the scrollable element hits the top side of the window, which is why I set the variable before running my code: `var scrollableTopOffset = $(".scrollable").offset().top;`). This offset would change anytime the window is resized, so I thought adding this would work (but it does not):

```
/* I need to make the idea of the following code work: */
  $( window ).resize(function() {
    /* First reset margin-top before getting offset again after resizing:  */
    $(".scrollable").stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
     });

     /* Secondly get the current offset after reset: */
     scrollableTopOffset = $(".scrollable").offset().top;
  });
  /* End of code what needs to be answered in my question */
```

Using the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var topPadding = 10;
  //Set the scrollable offset before starting the scroll
  var scrollableTopOffset = $(".scrollable").offset().top;

  /* I need to make the idea of the following code work: */
  $(window).resize(function() {
    /* First reset margin-top before getting offset again after resizing:  */
    $(".scrollable").stop().animate({
      marginTop: 0
    });

    /* Second get the current offset after reset: */
    scrollableTopOffset = $(".scrollable").offset().top;
  });
  /* End of code what needs to be answered in my question */

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    /* To make sure margin-top won't be applied so that the scrollable won't exceed the footer: */
    if (($("footer").offset().top - scrollableTopOffset + topPadding) < $(window).scrollTop()) {
      //Do nothing or add 0 margin:
      $(".scrollable").stop().animate({
        marginTop: 0
      });
    }
    /* When scrolling, determine wether the browser window still contains
  scrollable: */
    else if (scrollableTopOffset < $(window).scrollTop()) {
      //Code when scrollable is within the browser window...
      //$(".scrollable").addClass("scrollable-fixed");
      $(".scrollable").stop().animate({
        marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - scrollableTopOffset + topPadding
      });
    } else {
      //Code when scrollabe is not within the browser window...
      //$(".scrollable").removeClass("scrollable-fixed");
      $(".scrollable").stop().animate({
        marginTop: 0
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container .topmenu {
  height: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.some-content-block {
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
.some-other-content {
  height: 130px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.scrollable {
  height: 75px;
  background-color: cyan;
}
footer {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container" style="background-color: blue;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="some-content-block topmenu">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="some-other-content">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="some-other-content">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="some-content-block">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="some-content-block">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="some-content-block">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="some-content-block">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="some-content-block">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="some-content-block">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="some-content-block">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
      <div class="scrollable">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mebr8s44/4/)

Can anyone tell/expain me how I can make my code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$(window).resize()` listener does not work as desired, because you redeclare the variable locally instead of using your existing variable. Remove the `var` and that particular problem should be solved. So, you would be looking at

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    scrollableTopOffset = $(".scrollable").offset().top;
});
```

Edit:

Looks like you should consider getting the height of the 'safety zone' up top differently. It looks like you could just use `$('.topmenu').height()` instead of `$('.scrollable').offset().top`.

Edit again:

Is it really necessary to have such a complicated structure for your `topmenu` and related divs? Wouldn't something much simpler like the below work? With that, the first edit's suggested fix looks to work properly.

```
<div class="row some-content-block topmenu">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="some-other-content">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="some-other-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Though not directly related to your initial question, you should brush up on the [Bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to avoid future problems with visuals.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zaoeywy8/2/) with the changes to the `.topmenu` area that seems to work.

Comment: It would be a great comment but unfortunately not make my code work. Edit: Seemed like it does work but sometimes it is not working very well,   It looks kind of weird, since resizing and offset does not always make the code work but after another resize event it actually does sometimes.

Comment: @Barrosy, edited my answer with a different approach

Comment: Would that work? In my current fiddle it doesn't look like that, but your answer seems close to what I want to achieve. https://jsfiddle.net/zaoeywy8/

Comment: @Barrosy Your previous version seemed closer to what you want, now you are just overcomplicating things. Try to just replace `$('.scrolltop').offset().top` in your initial fiddle without all this originalOffset stuff, with `$('.topmenu').height()`

Comment: The moment the divs change width (e.g. Bootstrap col-medium to col-small) the offset is not right anymore, the scrollable stays at a further distance from the top. I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: The reason I add `col-md-6` is to make changes happen to the `height` of the `<div>` or other relative content above the scrollable element, to show what happens when this changes on window resize. One could say that is actually the core of this question.

Comment: @Barrosy Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110981/discussion-between-thernys-and-barrosy).

Answer (score 0):

define `scrollableTopOffset` globally

```
scrollableTopOffset = $(".scrollable").offset().top;

$(window).resize(function() {
    scrollableTopOffset = $(".scrollable").offset().top;
});
```

Comment: The scrollable element's properties are only loaded once the document is fully loaded, this would not work and I still tried it but this does not work.

Comment: Define the variable globally like this. I just removed "var"

scrollableTopOffset = $(".scrollable").offset().top;

Then update its value on each resize like below.

  $(window).resize(function() {
    scrollableTopOffset = $(".scrollable").offset().top;
  });

. If you use 'var', variable will be local to that function and the updated value of "scrollableTopOffset" from .resize() function will not be available in .scroll() function.

Comment: Yes I got what you're trying to say and your answer looks really similar to the one of Thernys. With defining the variable globally you mean right after or before the `$(document).ready()` ? I removed the var in my question, so that is not the point anymore.

Comment: I think I get what is happening now aswell: Once scrolled down and resizing, the offset of the scrollable element will be taken from then. Adding `margin-top: 0;` to the scrollable element would fix that, but it still seems off... (updated code in question).