# Calculate scaleTop automatically with the current window height

Tags: jquery

I have set the scaleTop property for a 1920x1080 window and it works well when I animate the scrolling. However when I resize the window, the scaleTop value does not work as expected due to the size of scrolling. For example in 1920x1080 window, setting scaleTop as 1500 moves a little forward. However when resizing window to smaller dimensions, scaleTop as 1500 moves alot ahead. So is there a formula to calculate the scaleTop to move to a target irrespective of window size?

```
$('a.FirstPage').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop:1500, //setting scaleTop value
            
        }, 2000, function() {
            parallaxScroll(); // Callback is required for iOS
            
            
        });
        return false;
    });

function parallaxScroll(){
        var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();

        $('#parallax-bg1').css('left',(0-(scrolled*1.0))+'px');

}
```

CSS

```
#parallax-bg1 {
        z-index: 1;
    
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 10px; /* 70px icon width + 10px margin */
        padding-top: 56.25%;/* 16:9 Aspect Ratio */

        left: 0%; /* align left edge with center of viewport */

        }
        #bg1-1 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0%;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        }

        #bg1-2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 78%;
        height: 100%;
        width:
```

HTML

```
<div id="parallax-bg1">
        <img  id="bg1-1" src="img/c.png" />
        <img id="bg1-2" src="img/c.png" />

</div>
```

Comment: are you trying to scroll to a specific element/section?

Comment: @Stender for now I have not set any element. I am scrolling to a specific position that is achievable only by setting to 1500.

Comment: @Stender I am setting these with divs, can I shift to a specific div's position with scroll top?

Comment: yeah, you can find the top position of any element with jquery, and make a dynamic "scrollTo" function like you have.

Comment: @Stender but the position of scrollTop changes with resizing window. So how do I implement what you suggested?

Comment: like `scrollTop: $("#div1").offset().top`

Comment: If you want to be safe, you can create a variable for each div, and set those variables on `$( window ).resize(function() {};`

Comment: @Stender could you please give me an example for the resize function?

Comment: sure : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37022871/4244684

Comment: @Stender thanks, I actually found a different problem. I will post it as new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is looking for an answer, this is how I calculated. Get the position of the div element. This will be calculated automatically when resizing window. Pass that value to scrollTop, Since I needed only the left position, I passed it as position.left. This is all one has to do. Very simple

```
$('a.FirstPage').click(function(){
var position = $('#parallax-bg1 #bg1-2').position();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop:position.left, //setting scaleTop value
            
        }, 2000, function() {
            parallaxScroll(); // Callback is required for iOS
            
            
        });
        return false;
    });

function parallaxScroll(){
        var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();

        $('#parallax-bg1').css('left',(0-(scrolled*1.0))+'px');

}
```